# How to replace text with keyframe animation text on hover?

Tags: javascript, css

When mouse hovers, keyframe animation plays fine... Although the original text does not disappear.

I have tried to create the hover keyframe animation to my best knowledge, although now stuck (is this better to do with javascript?).

```css
.name:hover::after {
  content: "";
  animation: descriptionChange 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes descriptionChange {
  0% {}
  10% {
    content: "Lorem";
  }
  20% {
    content: "delibus";
  }
  30% {
    content: "faccae";
  }
  40% {
    content: "repratia";
  }
  50% {
    content: "enviroments";
  }
  60% {
    content: "itation";
  }
  70% {
    content: "alique";
  }
  80% {
    content: "nuscitatiis";
  }
  90% {
    content: "quis";
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="name">description</span> <br>
```

Expected results:
• description text visible
• hover over description text to activate keyframe animation
• description text changes as the keyframe animation plays

Actual results:
• description text visible
• hover over description text to activate keyframe animation
• description text remains visible along with the keyframe animation description

Comment: The problem is  you are changing the `pseudo` content with your keyframe animation. You aren't affecting the content between the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `description` as your pseudo-element's `content` property. Currently it's your element's text-content and thus is not affected by your animation:

```css
.name::after {
  content: "description";
}
.name:hover::after {
  animation: descriptionChange 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes descriptionChange {
  0% {}
  10% {
    content: "Lorem";
  }
  20% {
    content: "delibus";
  }
  30% {
    content: "faccae";
  }
  40% {
    content: "repratia";
  }
  50% {
    content: "enviroments";
  }
  60% {
    content: "itation";
  }
  70% {
    content: "alique";
  }
  80% {
    content: "nuscitatiis";
  }
  90% {
    content: "quis";
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="name"></span> <br>
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. 
Is there a way to increase the hover state area? Because of the varying word lengths, the animation does not play through if the mouse hovers over the 'ion' in 'description' and then gets to a smaller word like 'Lorem' where the hover is no longer active.

Comment: I had a crack, and changed the 'span' to a 'div'. This fixed the word length glitch as mentioned above, although then made the 'description' move out of its original place. I then used 'position: relative;' and 'transform: translate(...%, ...%) to reposition the 'descriptor'.

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to keep your HTML structure intact (ie not wanting to add another DOM element), then one approach would be to hide the "description" text by assigning it a transparent color during `:hover`:

```
.name:hover {
  color:transparent;
}

/* Need to "reset" pseudo elements color to black */
.name:hover::before {
  color:black;
  content: "";
  animation: descriptionChange 3s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

Also note that I'm using `:before` rather than `:after` - this ensures that the animated description gives the appearnce of replacing the "description" text during hover:

```css
.name:hover {
  color:transparent;
}

.name:hover::before {
color:black;
  content: "";
  animation: descriptionChange 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes descriptionChange {
  0% {}
  10% {
    content: "Lorem";
  }
  20% {
    content: "delibus";
  }
  30% {
    content: "faccae";
  }
  40% {
    content: "repratia";
  }
  50% {
    content: "enviroments";
  }
  60% {
    content: "itation";
  }
  70% {
    content: "alique";
  }
  80% {
    content: "nuscitatiis";
  }
  90% {
    content: "quis";
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="name">description</span> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by wrapping your `description` text in another element:

```css
.name {
  position: relative;
}
.name:hover::after {
  content: "";
  animation: descriptionChange 3s linear infinite alternate;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.name:hover > span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes descriptionChange {
  0% {}
  10% {
    content: "Lorem";
  }
  20% {
    content: "delibus";
  }
  30% {
    content: "faccae";
  }
  40% {
    content: "repratia";
  }
  50% {
    content: "enviroments";
  }
  60% {
    content: "itation";
  }
  70% {
    content: "alique";
  }
  80% {
    content: "nuscitatiis";
  }
  90% {
    content: "quis";
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="name"><span>description</span></span> <br>
```